# How do I get a variable out of a class in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

Hi I don't get the variable out of the KeyCodeClass. Here is what I tryed:
**TEST 1**

```
class KeyCodeClass1 {
    constructor() {
        this.space;
    }
    KeyDown(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 32) { this.space = true }
    }
    KeyUp(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 32) { this.space = false }
    }
}

var KeyCode1 = new KeyCodeClass1();
window.addEventListener("keydown", KeyCode1.KeyDown, false);
window.addEventListener("keyup", KeyCode1.KeyUp, false);

setInterval(loop1,10);

function loop1() {
     console.log(KeyCode1.space);
}
```

Now I get in my console undefined. So if I press my spacebar what equals `e.keyCode == 32` the undefined stay's printed. So what if we return the value in a fuction we get this: **TEST 2**

```
class KeyCodeClass2 {
    constructor() {
        this.space;
    }
    KeyDown(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 32) { this.space = true }
    }
    KeyUp(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 32) { this.space = false }
    }
    Space() {
        return this.space;
    }
}

var KeyCode2 = new KeyCodeClass2();
window.addEventListener("keydown", KeyCode2.KeyDown, false);
window.addEventListener("keyup", KeyCode2.KeyUp, false);

setInterval(loop2,10);

function loop2() {
     console.log(KeyCode2.Space());
}
```

So still an undefined in the console. the 3 test where I did defined the `this.space` with a `true` or `false` in the constructor: **TEST 3**

```
constructor() {
    this.space = false;
}
```

Well we get the `false` in the console. But when I press the spacebar is goes not to `true`.

So I began to wonder whether the functions in the class are working. Here it is proved that they work fine: **TEST 4**

```
class KeyCodeClass4 {
    constructor() {
        this.space = false;
    }
    KeyDown(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 32) {
            KeyCodeClass.space = true;
            console.log("space Down");
        }
    }
    KeyUp(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 32) {
            KeyCodeClass.space = false;
            console.log("space Up");
        }
    }
}

var KeyCode4 = new KeyCodeClass4();
window.addEventListener("keydown", KeyCode4.KeyDown, false);
window.addEventListener("keyup", KeyCode4.KeyUp, false);
```

why am I doing this? it is to make my code more readable and understandable. Please help me with this problem.

Comment: (Unrelated to the main problem.) Note that `this.space;` in a constructor is a no-op. It looks up the value of `space` on `this` and then throws away that value. It doesn't "declare" `space` as an instance property or anything of that sort.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thx for the feed back I am still a student and my teachers are not specialized in JavaScript and was looking in the wrong direction for a solution. (about the duplicate). I got stuck on this problem for roughly 4 weeks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you are losing `this` context, so when your listeners are executed, `this` is not pointing to your class instance, but rather the `window` object. I'd try to do:

```
var KeyCode = new KeyCodeClass2();
window.addEventListener("keydown", KeyCode.KeyDown.bind(KeyCode), false);
window.addEventListener("keyup", KeyCode.KeyUp.bind(KeyCode), false);
```

Let me know if that works for you